# when do you configure rcu?

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

we want to know when i user RCU in configuration of weblogic domain?
which composants need connexion to database and need RCU?

regards

Comment: RCU is used by many Oracle products running on Oracle Fusion Middleware framework. this includes OSB, SOA, ODI, etc... It provides a persistent storage and a framework for data used by this framework.

Answer (score 0):

When installing most oracle fusion middleware stack, such as mentioned already here, SOA, OSB, ODI, OIM, OAM, BIP, etc. you need to install the RCU prior to installing any domains.

1. prep your servers -- os,jdk,tcp,hard/soft limits, etc
2. install the OFMW binaries
3. run the RCU for the given stack(s)
4. configure your domain

I hope this helps answer your question.